# Assigning random integer to selected rows within certain range

Tags: mysql, random

I want to assign an integer to a set of rows in a MySQL Database table.  I want the integer to be unique for each row from 1 to the number of rows in the table.  So if there are twenty rows matching specific criteria in the table I want to assign them each a number between 1 and 20 so that if selected by this number they will be returned randomly and not in the order they were entered.

Can anybody recommend a solution for this?

Thanks,
Mick

Answer (score 0):

There's a naive way to solve this and also a very cool and efficient way to solve this.

The naive way would be to make a list in memory of 0-20, shuffle it using a random number generator, and store the results back in the table.

The better way involves something called format preserving encryption, which is used in the real world for things like generating a new, cryptographically secure "random" credit card number and being garaunteed that the number hasn't been used before.

Basically using format preserving encryption, you'd transform each value 0-N into a new number that will also be 0-N using cryptographic techniques.  Due to the nature of encryption (mainly, that its reversible) you are guaranteed to not get duplicates (unlike a hash function). This gets to be amazingly more efficient than actually shuffling when N gets very large.

I suggest reading up on the topic.  In case it helps, check out my blog post on the subject:  http://blog.demofox.org/2013/07/06/fast-lightweight-random-shuffle-functionality-fixed/